# ntp doesn't sync - Server has gone too long without sync

Tags: ubuntu, ntpd

I'm unable to sync with ntp server. Any suggestions on how to force the ntpdate to work and sync?

ntp.conf on clients are default with only the `server` address changed.

```
ntpdate -dv 10.10.10.10
26 Sep 04:33:56 ntpdate[18934]: ntpdate 4.2.2p1@1.1570-o Mon Dec  9 14:35:05 UTC                                                                                                   2013 (1)
Looking for host 10.10.10.10 and service ntp
host found : 10.10.10.10
transmit(10.10.10.10)
receive(10.10.10.10)
transmit(10.10.10.10)
receive(10.10.10.10)
transmit(10.10.10.10)
receive(10.10.10.10)
transmit(10.10.10.10)
receive(10.10.10.10)
transmit(10.10.10.10)
10.10.10.10: Server dropped: Server has gone too long without sync
server 10.10.10.10, port 123
stratum 3, precision -22, leap 00, trust 000
refid [10.10.10.10], delay 0.02588, dispersion 0.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    ded53aa8.03ff145c  Wed, Jun 20 2018 20:42:16.015
originate timestamp: df558ac2.571e7c56  Wed, Sep 26 2018  4:34:10.340
transmit timestamp:  df558ab4.779ebe9c  Wed, Sep 26 2018  4:33:56.467
filter delay:  0.02611  0.02589  0.02588  0.02591
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: 13.87284 13.87281 13.87281 13.87279
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.02588, dispersion 0.00000
offset 13.872814

26 Sep 04:33:56 ntpdate[18934]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

Answer (score 3):

Note the reference time received back from the server: Wed, Jun 20 2018 20:42:16.015 - that means that the server has not syned with its upstream(s) since that time.  `ntpdate` considers this too long ago and will not sync with that server because it's probably giving bad time.  To fix `ntpdate` you need to fix the server.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue.

Steps:

- Restarted NTPD server.
- Edit  /etc/ntp.conf on client machine and change line `"server 10.10.10.10"` to `"server 10.10.10.10 prefer"`.
- Restart ntp client.
- Then run `ntpdate 10.10.10.10` and it sync's fine.

Comment: The actions you've taken on the client would have no effect on `ntpdate`'s behaviour; `ntpdate` and `/etc/ntp.conf` have no relation to each other.  Whatever was wrong, you've masked it with the server restart and it's probably now serving reasonable time to `ntpdate`.